# Vim. Close the quicklist and return to the original window

Tags: vim, vimrc

I'd like to write a function that toggles the quicklist and when closing it, it returns to the window it was in before the quicklist opening.
I tried to improve some function I found but it does not work as expected:

```
function! ToggleQuickFix()
    if empty(filter(getwininfo(), 'v:val.quickfix'))
        copen 20
    else
        call feedkeys("^W^P")
        cclose
    endif
endfunction
```

Comment: I've been using Vim for something like 10 or 15 years and never heard of quickfix before. It may help make the question easier to give a definitive answer to if you start it with some context about how to reproduce the undesirable default behavior? What "does not work as expected" about the function?

Comment: When I'm running grep from the command mode, I got the results in a window entitled [Quickfix list]. I have a shortcut to toggle it (F2). When I'm in a window A, as I said I can run the grep, when I press F2, I'd like to return to the original window A. Currently, when I close the Quickfix list, the active window is randomly chosen but I'd like to return to the original one. I'm using neoVim.